# Tuple Index out of range using .format() method

Tags: string, format, tuples

I am writing some very simple code for a random quote program - have read various threads on this issue but cannot spot my error. The error is triggered on the penultimate line. Thanks in advance.

`enter code here`
`enter code here`import random

```
quote_str = [
["Tis better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all",
        "Alfred Lord Tennyson"],
["To be or not to be, that is the question.","William Shakespeare"],
["No one can make you feel inferior without your consent.","Eleanor Roosevelt"],
["You are your best thing.","Toni Morrison"]]

x = random.choice([0,1,2,3])

quote = "Quote: {0} Author: {1}".format(quote_str[x][0])
print(quote)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed providing value for `{1}` for `quote`. Update `quote` to this and it works.

```
quote = "Quote: {0} Author: {1}".format(quote_str[x][0], quote_str[x][1])
```

**Output**

```
Quote: You are your best thing. Author: Toni Morrison
```

Comment: Thank you! A simple error on my part- I should have noticed it :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to above answer, you can also use `f-strings` if you are using `Python 3.6 and above`. You can use it as follows:

```
quote = f"Quote: {quote_str[x][0]} Author: {quote_str[x][1]}"
```